# VB6 Application Permission Denied Error 70 for Active Directory Users

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, vb6

I've setup a small Active Directory users for about 25, In every individual machine 
they run an old VB6 Application but some how the domain users can't run it, It raises an 
'Permission Denied: Error 70' but it works fine for domain administrators.

Is there anyway to solve this problem.

Comment: What's your client OS? Have you tried the various compatibility modes for applications?

Comment: Windows XP SP3 on Windows Server 2003 domain. As i mentioned it works pretty well for Domain Administrators and Local Administrators. It won't work as expected for Domain Users.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that LUA Buglight is often useful for diagnosing permissions problems.  It can usually tell you which resources the regular user doesn't have access to but admins do.

You run it as the user experiencing the problem, and also give it the username and password of a user that isn't experiencing the problem, usually an administrator. Then whenever the program experiences a permission issue, it retries the operation as the administrator and logs the access.

[Latest download](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2011/03/23/lua-buglight-2-1-1-with-support-for-win7-2008r2-sp1.aspx).

[Brief overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2009/11/03/luabuglight.aspx).

Comment: Looks like a great tool i'll let you know once i finish it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the permissions on all the relevant files, including all the library files, are such that normal users can access them. There may also be an issue with the application wanting to write t a file, perhaps an ini or similar, but normal users don't have write permissions. If all that checks out repeat for the application's registry entries.

Sometimes these issues are best sorted out by reinstalling as a user, rather than as an administrator.